# Typescript 2 definitions for mocha, jasmine cause duplicate identifiers

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Steps to reproduce:
1) `npm install @types/mocha @types/jasmine`
2) `tsc`

```
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(9,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'describe'.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(11,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'xdescribe'.
...
node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts(33,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'describe'.
node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts(34,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'xdescribe'.
...
```

My project structure:

```
node_modules
test.ts
tsconfig.json
```

My code:

```
const a: number = 9;
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it. Use the `types` option in `tsconfig.json` along with `tsc` version 2.x

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": []
  }
}
```